# Google+ Snippet Description

Tags: google-plus, social-networking, schema.org, rich-snippets

So I'm trying to get my page ready to share on social networks. `Twitter` cards is working fine with the `Twitter` meta tags. `Facebook` liking/sharing is working fine with the open graphics meta tags. But `Google+`, for some reason, is only pulling the image(s) and title, but for some reason is not pulling the description. What in the world is going wrong here?

```
<!doctype html>
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
<head>


<meta itemprop="name"           content="Plural Marriage Debate">
<meta itemprop="description"    content="Debate on the subject of plural marriage between Todd D. Webb and Allen W. McDaniel">
<meta name="description"        content="Debate on the subject of plural marriage between Todd D. Webb and Allen W. McDaniel">
<meta itemprop="publisher"      content="My Company Inc">
<meta itemprop="image"          content="http://www.example.com/20130124_224507.jpg">
<meta itemprop="image"          content="http://www.example.com/156.jpg">

<!-- Facebook Meta Tags -->
<meta property="fb:app_id"      content="####****####***" /> 
<meta property="og:type"        content="website" /> 
<meta property="og:title"       content="Plural Marriage Debate" />
<meta property="og:site_name"   content="My Company Inc"/>
<meta property="og:image"       content="http://www.example.com/20130124_224507.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Debate on the subject of plural marriage between Todd D. Webb and Allen W. McDaniel" /> 
<meta property="og:url"         content="http://www.example.com/video.php">

<!-- Twitter card tags -->
<meta name="twitter:card"           content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site"           content="@ScreenName">
<meta name="twitter:title"          content="Plural Marriage Debate">
<meta name="twitter:description"    content="Debate on the subject of plural marriage between Todd D. Webb and Allen W. McDaniel">
<meta name="twitter:creator"        content="@ScreenName">
<meta name="twitter:image"          content="http://www.example.com/20130124_224507.jpg">
<meta name="twitter:domain"         content="http://www.example.com/video.php">

<title>Plural Marriage Debate</title>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see how Google will view your site using the Rich Snippets Tool here: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Google is pushing for [WebSchemas](http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas) as the standard mechanism for embedding metadata on the Web, however, Google+ can fallback to OpenGraph if that's what's available. Incidentally, when I take your snippet above and drop it into our tool, I get the correct output.

More likely what you're seeing is an element of the recent site redesign, where our snippets no longer display the Description. I am not entirely sure why that decision was made, but it is by design.

Comment: Yeah, I used that tool earlier and got the same results you did. That's what got me even more perplexed. So I'm guessing from your response of Google+ doing away with the description in snippets, that what I'm experiencing is the new norm and that's the way that it's actually supposed to be?

Comment: @TheDukeOfMarshall Yeah, it's definitely behaving correctly based on the current implementation.